# boost graph copy and removing vertex

Tags: c++, boost, graph

How do I copy a boost graph into a second boost graph so that I can use the vertex descriptor extracted from the first graph to modify the second one without modifying the first one ?

I have a boost graph `g1` from which I extracted a couple of vertex descriptor. Now I want to use this vertex descriptor to do some processing to a copy of `g1` named `g2`. If I use something along the lines of :

```
g2 = g1;
```

to copy the graph then I can access the vertex properties of `g2` using vertex descriptor extracted from `g1` using something like `g2[vertex_descriptor]` but I cannot remove a vertex from the graph.

```
boost::clear_vertex(v, _graph);
boost::remove_vertex(v, _graph);
```

Does nothing to my graph and the vertex is still there.

I know there is a `copy_graph` function available but I don't really understand (or I don't know how to read) the [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/copy_graph.html) and doing `boost::copy_graph(g1, g2)` yield a lot of errors :

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:246:0,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/TopologicalMap/Global.hpp:6,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapComparator/Match.hpp:4,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapComparator/Hypothese.hpp:4,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapComparator/Cluster.hpp:4,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/Test/test_comparisor.cpp:11:
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::adj_list_any_vertex_pa::bind_<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, topologicalmap::Place>’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2568:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::adj_list_choose_vertex_pa<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, topologicalmap::Place>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2705:12:   required from ‘struct boost::adj_list_vertex_property_selector::bind_<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, topologicalmap::Place, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:217:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:228:10:   required from ‘struct boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, boost::vertex_index_t, void>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:1688:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Config, class Base, class Property> typename boost::property_map<typename Config::graph_type, Property>::const_type boost::get(Property, const boost::adj_list_helper<Config, Base>&) [with Config = boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config; Base = boost::undirected_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>, boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config>; Property = boost::vertex_index_t]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/copy.hpp:353:57:   required from ‘void boost::copy_graph(const VertexListGraph&, MutableGraph&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>; MutableGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>]’
/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapComparator/Cluster.hpp:32:150:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2498:29: error: forming reference to void
         typedef value_type& reference;
                             ^
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2499:35: error: forming reference to void
         typedef const value_type& const_reference;
                                   ^
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2502:47: error: forming reference to void
           <Graph, value_type, reference, Tag> type;
                                               ^
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2504:53: error: forming reference to void
           <Graph, value_type, const_reference, Tag> const_type;
                                                     ^
In file included from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/TopologicalMap/GraphPlace.hpp:13:0,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapComparator/Cluster.hpp:5,
                 from /home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/Test/test_comparisor.cpp:11:
/usr/include/boost/graph/copy.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::copy_graph(const VertexListGraph&, MutableGraph&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>; MutableGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>]’:
/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapComparator/Cluster.hpp:32:150:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/copy.hpp:353:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(boost::vertex_index_t, const boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, topologicalmap::Place, topologicalmap::Gateway_struct, boost::no_property>&)’
                                   get(vertex_index, g_in), orig2copy[0]),
```

The error message is bigger than that but I took only the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### *What's wrong with the naive approach?*

As I commented on the other answer, simply removing a vertex by the source vertex-descriptor will **not** work as expected, because it invalidates all the higher vertices in the mutated copy.

So if you were to remove a second vertex, chances are that you'd be removing *a different* vertex than the one intended.

What's worse, all the property lookups would be invalid (if done against original property maps).

And for the clincher, **none of this would work at all** if the vertex descriptor wasn't an integral type to begin with, e.g. when the vertex container selector was something else than `boost::vecS` (listS, setS etc.).

#### *How to solve it?*

The BGL has two primitives that seem applicable here:

1. [Filtered Graphs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/filtered_graph.html);

   Here you do not create an actual copy, just create a "filtered view" of the original graph by supplying (optional) vertex and edge filtering predicates.
2. [Subgraphs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/subgraph.html)

   This is most suitable if you want a two-way mutable relation between (nested) parent and child graphs. I.e. if you know *while building the graphs* what nodes are in which "level" of a graph "hierarchy", you can express that with `boost::subgraph<>` hierarchies. These will automatically stay in synch; i.e. if you add a node to a child graph, the parent graph will contain it too; if you modify/remove an edge in a child graph, the same changes are "live" reflected in all parent graphs.

In this scenario I think that `filtered_graph<>` is really close to your need. Here's a demo that writes the graph, and "live-filters" it using a `std::set<vertex_descriptor>`. The result is visualized using GraphViz:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7dbbf23e3544fe1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

struct VertexProperties {
    int id;
    std::string label;
};

struct EdgeProperties {
    double weight;
};

using Graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<listS, listS, directedS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// saving dotfiles for rendering to PNG
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

template <typename G>
void save_dot_file(std::string const& fname, G& graph) {
    dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", boost::get(&VertexProperties::id,    graph));
    dp.property("label",   boost::get(&VertexProperties::label, graph));
    dp.property("weight",  boost::get(&EdgeProperties::weight,  graph));

    std::ofstream ofs(fname);
    write_graphviz_dp(ofs, graph, dp);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filtering graphs with a simple vertex filter
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using V        = Graph_t::vertex_descriptor;
using Filtered = filtered_graph<Graph_t, keep_all, boost::function<bool(V)> >;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Demo
int main()
{
    Graph_t g;

    // have a filtered "copy" f that just removes a set of vertices:
    std::set<V> removed_set;
    Filtered f(g, keep_all{}, [&](V v){ return removed_set.end() == removed_set.find(v); });

    // build a demo graph with 3 vertices
    auto u = boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties{ 10, "Ten"    }, g);
    auto v = boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties{ 20, "Twenty" }, g);
    auto w = boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties{ 30, "Thirty" }, g);

    /*auto e1 =*/ boost::add_edge(u, v, EdgeProperties { 0.5 }, g);
    /*auto e2 =*/ boost::add_edge(v, w, EdgeProperties { 1.5 }, g);
    /*auto e3 =*/ boost::add_edge(w, u, EdgeProperties { 2.5 }, g);

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // save the original graph
    save_dot_file("original.dot", g);

    // empty filter:
    save_dot_file("filtered1.dot", f);

    // removing `v` ("Twenty")
    removed_set.insert(v);
    save_dot_file("filtered2.dot", f);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Daniel-san :) Since you're interested in BGL and had a working sample there, you might want to know about `filtered_graph` as demoed. Just so you don't think that was very easy: you can see the live-coding stream of my struggles here: [part #1](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-filtered-graphs-part-1/), [part #2](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-filtered-graphs-part-2/)  and [part #3](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-filtered-graphs-part-3/)

Comment: Looking at your explanation, graph filtered fit my usage more. My new problem is that I also need to be able to add edges to my second graph (without modifying the first one) as well and from what I read graph filtered doesn't allow this. But this wasn't in my question to beginning with and it solves the vertex problem. For the edge I feel like I can simply add some edge, save the descriptors somewhere and then suppress them from the graph, at the end of the processing, later. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could make both graphs filtered from a super-graph. But by this time, you should first get all the requirements/use patterns charted. It's starting to veer more towards `subgraph<>` already

Comment: I think that would be the best way to do it actually. But it would imply a lot of rewriting now. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I just want to comment on one API "limitation" of filtered_graphs.
`num_vertices(filtered_graph)` and `num_edges(filtered_graph)` will return the num of nodes and edges of the original graph.
You would need to use `boost::vertices(filtered_graph)` and `boost::nodes(filtered_graph)` and count them to get the right value.