# boost graph removing edges vs filtered_graph performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, graph, boost-graph

A single threaded boost graph that repeatedly removes and then adds same  edges later seems to be faster than a multi-threaded filtered_graph that uses edge predicates to concurrently do the same on multiple filtered graphs of the same underlying graph.

Possibly, filtered_graph traverses each and every edge and applies the predicate.

Is there a way to directly generate a filtered_graph without predicates i.e. use functions like remove_edge but actually create a filtered_graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`copy_graph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/copy_graph.html) on the filtered graph:

- [boost graph copy and removing vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522732/boost-graph-copy-and-removing-vertex/31527110#31527110)

Comment: This indeed seems to be faster than using the filtered graph itself. Is it really the case that the filter predicates are re-evaluated each time an edge is accessed? Or what is the reason for this speed difference?

Comment: @lucidbrot I'm not sure whether optimizations are in place, but I imagine it would be very hard to get that correctly generically (graph concepts are _very_ generic) so, yeah, it makes  a bit of sense.