# Make a boost filtered_graph by vertex label property

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-graph

Currently, I have a graph, that I keep tracking of `vertices` and `labels` by means of an `external map`. So anytime I need to access the label property, I find the label in the map and get the `mapped vertex`.

```
/// vertex properties
struct VertexData
{
    std::string label;
    int num;
};

/// edges properties
struct EdgeData
{
    std::string edge_name;
    double edge_confidence;
};

/// define the boost-graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
        boost::bidirectionalS,
        boost::property<boost::edge_index_t , size_t , VertexData>,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, EdgeData> > Graph;

/// define vertexMap
std::map<std::string, vertex_t> vertexMap;

///loop through the vertices to make the vertexMap here ...
vertexMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, vertex_t> (label, v));

/// find any label in the map and access the corresponding vertex
vertex_t vertex = vertexMap.find(label)->second;
```

Now my question is:
If I want to make a `filtered_graph` from current graph by filtering some labels, how should I do that in the `class template`? The examples in the boost graph library are different, and I checked also this post [boost graph copy and removing vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522732/boost-graph-copy-and-removing-vertex/31527110#31527110) but it's quite different from what I want to do.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Filtering

You need a filtering predicate. You *can* have multiple for different graph elements. But let's focus on vertices.

What you want is a stateful predicate. The way to do this is usually keeping the state outside the predicate and putting a pointer to that inside the predicate:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aef66927f419e8aa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

/// vertex properties
struct VertexData {
    std::string label;
    int num;
};

/// edges properties
struct EdgeData {
    std::string edge_name;
    double edge_confidence;
};

/// define the boost-graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
        boost::bidirectionalS,
        VertexData,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, EdgeData> > Graph;

int main() {
    using vertex_t = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    Graph g;
    for (auto label : { "alerts", "amazed", "buster", "deaths", "ekes", "Enoch", "gale", "hug", "input", "knifed", "lire", "man", "pithy", "Purims", "Rodger", "suckle", "Terr", "theme", "tiling", "vases", }) {
        boost::add_vertex(VertexData{label, 1+rand()%5}, g);
    }

    boost::write_graphviz(std::cout, g, boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&VertexData::label, g)));

    {
        using labels = std::set<std::string>;
        labels suppressed { "alerts", "amazed", "deaths", "ekes", "gale", "hug", "input", "knifed", "man", "pithy", "Purims", "suckle", "Terr", "theme", "vases", };

        struct Predicate { // both edge and vertex
            bool operator()(Graph::edge_descriptor) const      { return true; } // all
            bool operator()(Graph::vertex_descriptor vd) const { return suppressed_->count((*g)[vd].label) == 0; }

            Graph* g;
            labels* suppressed_;
        } predicate {&g, &suppressed};

        using Filtered = boost::filtered_graph<Graph, Predicate, Predicate>;
        Filtered fg(g, predicate, predicate);
        boost::write_graphviz(std::cout, fg, boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&VertexData::label, fg)));
    }

}
```

Prints the unfiltered graph (`g`) first, and then the filtered graph (`fg`):

```
digraph G {
2[label=buster];
5[label=Enoch];
10[label=lire];
14[label=Rodger];
18[label=tiling];
}
```

### Indexing

Not really the question, but you can make maintaining an index slightly more friendly using intrusive containers. If you add a hook to the VertexData:

```
struct VertexData : bi::set_base_hook<> {
    std::string label;
    int num;

    struct by_label;
};
```

You can use an intrusive-set:

```
using by_label_idx_t = bi::set<VertexData, bi::key_of_value<VertexData::by_label> >;
```

This means you can add all vertices:

```
by_label_idx_t label_idx;
for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
    label_idx.insert(g[vd]);
```

What does this buy you? Not a lot per se. But enabling auto-unlinking, it does buy you that when a vertex is removed, it's automatically removed from the index.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b7a743ae4389ad9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/set_hook.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

/// vertex properties
struct VertexData : bi::set_base_hook<bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink>, bi::constant_time_size<false> > {
    std::string label;
    int num;

    VertexData(std::string label, int num) : label(label), num(num) {}

    struct by_label {
        using type = std::string;
        std::string const& operator()(VertexData const& vd) const { return vd.label; }
    };
};

using by_label_idx_t = bi::set<VertexData, bi::constant_time_size<false>, bi::key_of_value<VertexData::by_label> >;

/// edges properties
struct EdgeData {
    std::string edge_name;
    double edge_confidence;
};

/// define the boost-graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
        boost::bidirectionalS,
        VertexData,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, EdgeData> > Graph;

int main() {
    using vertex_t = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    Graph g;
    for (auto label : { "alerts", "amazed", "buster", "deaths", "ekes", "Enoch", "gale", "hug", "input", "knifed", "lire", "man", "pithy", "Purims", "Rodger", "suckle", "Terr", "theme", "tiling", "vases", }) {
        boost::add_vertex(VertexData{label, 1+rand()%5}, g);
    }

    /// define vertexMap
    by_label_idx_t label_idx;
    auto reindex = [&] {
        label_idx.clear();
        for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
            label_idx.insert(g[vd]);
    };

    reindex();
    std::cout << "Index: " << label_idx.size() << " elements\n";

    g.clear();
    std::cout << "Index: " << label_idx.size() << " elements\n";

    for (auto& vertex : label_idx) {
        std::cout << vertex.label << " " << vertex.num << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If instead of having a `labels suppressed`, I want to do the filter conditionally, for example _if the label starts with an `a`_ then how is it possible with predicate? I understand that I can make a filter of labels beforehand but I prefer not to do that. And another question is why the `boost::filtered_graph<Graph, Predicate, Predicate>` has two times `Predicate`? One is for edge another for vertex? or there is another reason?

Comment: Can you write C++ code? C++ is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) so, yes: [`return l.size()>0 && l[0] == 'a';`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09bdb3363866fcaf). If _that_ was the part tripping you up, why wasn't it in the question? I gave you the more complicated thing because I assumed the simple case wouldn't give you trouble (see "stateful predicate" in the answer text)

Comment: Combined with the lambda technique from the other answer you linked, you can make that [even "simpler"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95b54fcd2b93f570).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on indexing, it was also my concern. I 've read you other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296206/bgl-indexing-a-vertex-by-keys, and I was not familiar with intrusive containers, after all I consider myself beginner in C++. So I try your suggestion.