# should I keep track of vertex descriptors in boost graph library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a graph instantiated with the following:

```
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, uint32_t> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, uint32_t> VertexProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS,
                              boost::undirectedS, VertexProperty,
                              EdgeWeightProperty, boost::setS> Graph;
```

I need to update this graph, e.g. add or remove edges. Since I'm using a set to store the vertices, I can't use their index, but I can keep a map:

```
unordered_map<uint32_t, Vertex_Descriptor>
```

That maps my indexes to vertices descriptors, so I can then later access directly in BGL, this approach works but adds this map overhead.

Can I somehow specify a custom index or what to compare when getting/putting vertices in the BGL? Or keeping vertices descriptors in a map is the best approach?

Full example at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe8e0f49a474d7fd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Notes:

1. Consider the rather underdocumented `labeled_graph<>` adaptor. I believe it's used in the library samples and also I [have a number of answers using it on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=labeled_graph+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) (Disclaimer: I also found a number of bugs in it, so YMMV)
2. Your own global `add_vertex` helper isn't being used, even if you did write:

   ```
   const auto vd = add_vertex(i, g);
   ```

   Beware of ADL! You named the function `add_vertex` and unless you wrote `(add_vertex)(i, g)` ADL would find the overload in `boost` because `adjacency_list<>` is from that namespace (among other related types).

   So, you can drop your helper function and still write it like that using the boost `add_vertex` overload taking a property: [`MutablePropertyGraph` concept, under "Valid Expressions"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/MutablePropertyGraph.html):

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        id_vertex[i] = add_vertex(i, g);
   ```
3. Also replacing the loop to print the graph you can use `print_graph`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7ce7d6e6f32df5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, uint32_t> VertexProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, uint32_t> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperty, EdgeWeightProperty,
                              boost::setS> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertex_it;

int main() {
    Graph g;
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, Vertex> id_vertex;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        id_vertex[i] = add_vertex(i, g);

    std::pair<vertex_it, vertex_it> vp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        add_edge(id_vertex[i], id_vertex[i + 1], g);

    clear_vertex(id_vertex[2], g);
    remove_vertex(id_vertex[2], g);

    print_graph(g);
}
```

Prints

```
0 <--> 1 
1 <--> 0 
3 <--> 4 
4 <--> 3 5 
5 <--> 4 6 
6 <--> 5 7 
7 <--> 6 8 
8 <--> 7 9 
9 <--> 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The helper function was a residue from other code. Is sad that I must pretty much double the space of the program for it to work properly. One would expect a way to overload the vertices ids :(

Comment: Ideas: You don't have to keep the external index around at all times. You can also use a vector for more effective allocation. See also these answers touching on using intrusive containers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296206/bgl-indexing-a-vertex-by-keys and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845469/make-a-boost-filtered-graph-by-vertex-label-property/45850742#45850742